Rot -OR- termites
Pulled some clapboards off and found this underneath....
Doesn't feel wet, however, we've had a dry spell here.


1

Get an expert to look at it, which I am not. But what I can see like like dry rot to me

It doesn't look like there is any termite frass present.
